# Why does the absolute value not matter here? $\int\frac{1}{|u|\sqrt{u^2-1}} = sec^{-1}(u)+C$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Recall $$\int\frac{1}{|u|\sqrt{u^2-1}} = sec^{-1}(u)+C$$

So, why does this work?

$$\int\frac{sin(x)dx}{cos(x)\sqrt{cos^2(x)-1}} $$
Let $u = cos(x)$

$du = -six(x)dx$

$$= -\int\frac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}  = - sec^{-1}(cos(x))+C$$

Notice in the denominator you only have a $u$ and not a $|u|$
Why is this ok?  Can you guarantee the cos(x) is always (+) thereby making  the absolute value moot?  Otherwise, it seems the last step is not a correct evaluation of the given integral up top.

---

EDIT:   Ok, is this one valid?  Notice there is just a "u" and not a "|u|" in the denominator.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. Notice that $\sqrt{\cos^2(x) - 1}$ isn't defined for most x.

Comment: The solution is wrong?

Comment: Yep. That is not integrable. Another way to see is to realize that $-\sec^{-1} (\cos(x)) = -\frac1x$. The derivative of that is definitely not the original question.

Comment: Kaynex, thanks.  Can you look at the 2nd example I posted in the original post?  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how useful this could be for your problem, but notice that for 
$$f(\theta) = \frac{\sin (\theta )}{\cos (\theta ) \sqrt{\cos ^2(\theta )-1}} ,$$

$\Re(f(\theta))=0, \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$, so your integration is happening in the $\Im(f(\theta))$ strictly.

So, without many formalities, you can change the integration to $$-\mathrm{i} \int \frac{\sin (\theta )}{\cos (\theta ) \sqrt{1-\cos ^2(\theta )}} \, d\theta = -\mathrm{i} \int \sec (\theta) \, d\theta$$

From complex calculus we have
$$-\mathrm{i} \int \sec (\theta) \, d\theta = \mathrm{i} -\left| \log  \left| \frac{\cos  \theta }{\sin  \theta +1}\right| \right|.$$

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Can you look at the 2nd example I posted in the original post?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I miss read your formula. Your answer for the second example is right.