# Why does integral equation for arcsec have absolute value in its argument rather than the denominator of the integrand?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, proof-writing, inverse

In this question, I would like to investigate the location of the absolute value in the arcsecant integral.

Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3735966/why-the-derivative-of-inverse-secant-has-an-absolute-value) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449228/deriving-the-derivative-formula-for-arcsecant-correctly?rq=1), we know the following is true:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\sec^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}.
$$
Taking indefinite integrals of both sides, we get
$$
\sec^{-1}(x)+C=\int \frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx
$$
How can one use this result to deduce that
$$
\sec^{-1}(|x|)+C=\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx?
$$
(Notice that the absolute values used to be in the denominator of the right hand side, and now they are in the argument of the $\sec^{-1}$ function.)

What logical rule of deduction allows us to interchange the location of the absolute values on opposite sides of this equation?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564943/why-does-the-absolute-value-not-matter-here-int-frac1u-sqrtu2-1-se?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that

$$ \sec^{-1}(u)+C=\int \frac{1}{|u|\sqrt{u^2-1}} du $$

let $u=|x|$. Then $du=\dfrac{|x|}{x}dx$ and

\begin{eqnarray}
\sec^{-1}(|x|) +C&=&\int\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{|x|^2-1}}\cdot \frac{|x|}{x}\,dx\\
&=& \int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx?
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This was very elegant! I liked your use of the $\textrm{sgn}(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$ function. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

For nonnegative $x,$ the required implication is self-evident; so, let's suppose that $x$ is negative, in which case $|x|=-x.$ Then, noting that $\left(\sec^{-1}(x)-\frac\pi2\right)$ is an odd function,

\begin{align}\sec^{-1}(|x|)&=\sec^{-1}(-x)\\&=\left(\sec^{-1}(-x)-\frac\pi2\right)+\frac\pi2\\&=-\left(\sec^{-1}(x)-\frac\pi2\right)+\frac\pi2\\&=-\sec^{-1}(x)+\pi\\&=-\left(\int \frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}} \,\mathrm dx-C\right)+\pi\\&=\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} \,\mathrm dx+C+\pi\\\sec^{-1}(|x|)+C_2&=\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} \,\mathrm dx.\end{align}

Comment: This was very helpful - I appreciate your answer! I wish I could accept both answers. Thank you!